# WPF: Binding with two different lists

Tags: c#, wpf, list, listbox

I have a few Problems with databinding in WPF.

I have a ListBox which has a binding to a BindingList.

```
<ListBox x:Name="SampleListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding List1}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxStyle}" BorderThickness="0" SelectedIndex="0" Margin="0">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <Border x:Name="border" Width="185">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}"/>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Till here, everything works fine. Now I have a DataGrid which should be linked to another BindingList and display some strings of it. So for example, if the first item of the ListBox is selected, the grid should show data of the first item of the second list.
I know, how it would work if both, the ListBox and the Grid get the data from the same list, but I have no idea, what to do, if this is not possible and there are two different lists.

Answer (score 0):

You could bind SelectedIndex for the ListBox control to an property of type Int (Property1) in your ViewModel.

Also two-way bind SelectedItem in the DataGrid to another property (Property2) of the second list type.

In the setter for the Property1, change Property2 to be the item at the index of Property1 - i.e. List2[Property1]. It should change the selected item in the DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to use the listbox to, essentially, set a filter on the grid?

Note that LBItem and ViewModel below need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and fire their PropertyChanged events when properties change, or none of this will work. But I'm leaving out the boilerplate for clarity.

Lots of ways to do that.

C#

```
public class LBItem {
    public ViewModel Parent { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<String> SubItems {
        get {
            return Parent.List2.Where( /* filter items here */ );
        }
    }
}

public class ViewModel {
    //  
    public ObservableCollection<LBItem> LBItems { get; set; }
    public LBItem SelectedLBItem { get; set; } 
    public List<String> List2 { get; set; }
}
```

XAML

```
<ListBox 
    Name="MasterLB"
    ItemsSource="{Binding LBItems}" 
    SelectedItem={Binding SelectedLBItem}"
    />

<DataGrid
    ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MasterLB, Path=SelectedItem.SubItems}"
    />
```

That will work whether or not you bind `MasterLB.SelectedItem` to a property on the ViewModel. But as long as you are binding `MasterLB.SelectedItem`, you could just as easily bind `DataGrid.ItemsSource` to `SelectedLBItem.SubItems` on the ViewModel, like so:

```
<DataGrid
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedLBItem.SubItems}"
    />
```

But the ElementName binding is handy for a lot of things, so I'm giving you both.

You could also do something like this:

C#

```
public class LBItem {
    public IEnumerable<String> Filter(IEnumerable<String> fullList) {
        return fullList.Where( /* filter items here */ );
    }
}

public class ViewModel {
    public ObservableCollection<LBItem> LBItems { get; set; }
    private LBItem _selectedItem;
    public LBItem SelectedLBItem { 
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set {
            _selectedItem = value;
            List2Filtered = (null == _selectedItem) 
                ? new List<String>() 
                : _selectedItem.Filter(List2).ToList();
        }
    } 
    public List<String> List2 { get; set; }
    public List<String> List2Filtered { get; set; }
}
```

XAML

```
<ListBox 
    Name="MasterLB"
    ItemsSource="{Binding LBItems}" 
    SelectedItem={Binding SelectedLBItem}"
    />

<DataGrid
    ItemsSource="{Binding List2Filtered}"
    />
```